# How to capture IP address and Useragent from Vhosts in one log file

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

Currently I have a number of virtualhosts in my Apache 2.4 httpd file.  I'd like to be able to capture more info on who is visiting and when, including the IP Address and User Agent in the access_log.

In httpd conf file I have this:

```
` <IfModule log_config_module>
    # info from http://www.techstacks.com/howto/log-client-ip-and-xforwardedfor-ip-in-apache.html
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" proxy
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined env=!forwarded
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" proxy env=forwarded
</IfModule>
```

Which results in this:
    `At the moment, it shows this:

```
`::1 - - [05/Aug/2016:02:49:26 +1200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 (internal dummy connection)"``
```

I also tried various other suggested configs found on here and in google, but so far I am not having any luck.

My understanding is that since the logging directive is outside the  record, it should capture the specified traffic ([detailed here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#virtualhost))- but as you can see from the example, it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

The connection log you posted was a internal connection, used by apache to keep a worker alive. It's not actually a visitor at all! The out-of-the-box "combined" format should by default give you the log entries you seek.

That would be the following LogFormat:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

and then, in your VirtualHost block, you want the following:

```
CustomLog /path/to/access_log combined
```

If you're behind a reverse-proxy cache, this becomes a bit more interesting, but an apache module such as mod-rpaf should help with that.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer.  Please explain "The connection log you posted was a internal connection".  As I asked in my question, according to Apache documentation, it is my understanding there's no need to place the logging directive in the actual VirtualHost block.  I'm looking for a way to have a combined "master" access_log that shows traffic to all VHs. The logging directive you've mentioned already exists in each of my VH - so that is not an issue.  Perhaps a better qstn would be "how to combine VH logs into a master log" ?

Comment: The CustomLog line you posted was not a log entry caused by a visitor. It was a log entry caused by apache itself.

To have one master log, just have the CustomLog entries pointing at the same file. The ones in vhosts might be redundant, if they're not needed.